# Backup with mariabackup error Can't open dir ./System Volume Information

Tags: mariadb

I attempt to create a backup of Mariadb on a Windows installation. My commando `C:\wamp\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.7.3\bin\mariabackup.exe --backup --target-dir=E:\mariadb-backup\ --user=root --password=`

Ends in :

```
[00] 2022-09-08 11:53:15 Connecting to MariaDB server host: localhost, user: root, password: set, port: 3306, socket: /tmp/mariadb.sock
[00] 2022-09-08 11:53:15 Using server version 10.7.3-MariaDB
C:\wamp\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.7.3\bin\mariabackup.exe based on MariaDB server 10.7.3-MariaDB Win64 (AMD64)
[00] 2022-09-08 11:53:15 cd to c:\wamp\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.7.3\data\
[00] 2022-09-08 11:53:15 open files limit requested 0, set to 0
[00] 2022-09-08 11:53:15 mariabackup: using the following InnoDB configuration:
[00] 2022-09-08 11:53:15 innodb_data_home_dir =
[00] 2022-09-08 11:53:15 innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend:max:500M
[00] 2022-09-08 11:53:15 innodb_log_group_home_dir = ./
2022-09-08 11:53:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
[00] 2022-09-08 11:53:15 mariabackup: Generating a list of tablespaces
[00] 2022-09-08 11:53:15 Can't open dir ./System Volume Information
[00] 2022-09-08 11:53:15 merror: xb_load_tablespaces() failed with error Generic error.
```

Apparently dir ./System Volume Information cannot be opened.
How do I successfully make a backup with mariadbbackup?

Edit: the data folder is a mounted vhd.

Comment: I'd suspect this is a permission denied based on windows user. Why is it accessing this directory when the datadir is different?

Comment: @danblack That is a very good question. Not sure what mariabackup.exe needs the `System Volume` for

Comment: mariabackup won't need it. Given its `./Sys...` I assume that the directory its been run from. Try a different run directory.

Comment: @danblack It is not. I'm not sure if you are familiar with the function of /System Volume Information  on Windows